# Windows command that returns external IP

Tags: windows, command-line, ip

Is there a command by which I can find my external IP of my router or my NAT\DSL Router, etc., eliminating the need to visit whatsmyip.net or similar.

Comment: Linux: http://askubuntu.com/questions/95910/command-for-determining-my-public-ip/712144#712144

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no built-in command to do this. Part of the problem is that when you are connected to the internet through a router, your network hardware is not directly connected to the internet, so your system isn't specifically assigned an IP. It's possible you might even have multiple external IPs in some cases if you are behind a reverse proxy, as many corporate networks are set up. Your best bet might be to create a script which queries [whatismyip.org](http://whatismyip.org/), or trying to find if one already exists.

(As a tip, whatismyip.org is preferable to most other solutions, since it just returns your IP as plain text - no superfluous text, links, images or other garbage. It would be much easier to use in a custom script than most of the other IP-detection sites.)

Comment: They changed whatismyip.org, unfortunately; the IP address is now returned as an *image*, making it pretty much useless for scripting. The website "icanhazip.com" mentioned below *does* work.

Comment: Yandex is working, check the script posted below.

Comment: Working native command from below 
https://superuser.com/a/722397/216374

Answer (score 162):

You could use a DNS request instead of HTTP request to find out your public IP:

```
C:\> nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com
```

It uses `resolver1.opendns.com` dns server to resolve the magical `myip.opendns.com.` hostname to *your* ip address. (Note: the trailing `.` on the lookup prevents search domains from being appended, which can yield incorrect results.)

Unix version:

```
$ dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: brilliant, works without installing anything too.

Comment: Didn't work for me anymore in November, 2017, on Windows 10. PowerShell answer from Bradley Forney works.

Comment: Worked for me still (Windows 10, Dec 2017). Very clever @jfs, do OpenDNS have this documented somewhere how did you discover it?

Comment: @AlexKeySmith: I do not remember.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it provides an actual command, and it works. The accepted answer tells there is no command (which is proved false), and suggests using a script, without really giving further direction.

Comment: works for me it returns correct external ip adress

Comment: That's the correct answer to me. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Saved me a ton of unnecessary hassle writing this script for multiple windows servers. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 49):

grab your own copy of `curl`from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html and then just

```
curl "http://myexternalip.com/raw"
```

or use powershell:

```
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadString("http://myexternalip.com/raw")
```

(disclaimer: http://myexternalip.com was created by me)

Comment: That only provides an IPv6 address. Is there a way to get the IPv4 address?

Comment: I kept reading and found the IPv4 / IPv6 examples below for Powershell. It is possible to get IPv4 with CURL like this "C:>curl "http://myip.dnsomatic.com/"

Comment: Thanks. A shorter PowerShell command would be "(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://myexternalip.com/raw).Content" that just returns the URL.

Answer (score 10):

This works nicely, I use it mostly with psexec when inspecting client computer connections.

```
nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com
```

Answer (score 7):

Create a file named `ip.vbs` and copy the following into it:

```
Option Explicit
Dim http : Set http = CreateObject( "MSXML2.ServerXmlHttp" )
http.Open "GET", "http://icanhazip.com", False
http.Send
Wscript.Echo http.responseText   'or do whatever you want with it
Set http = Nothing
```

Execute using

```
C:\>cscript ip.vbs
```

As nhinkle [noted](https://superuser.com/questions/165986/command-prompt-command-for-external-ip/165998#165998), it's best to choose a site that only returns the IP and not HTML + ads, etc. like:

- http://myip.dnsomatic.com
- http://whatismyip.org
- http://icanhazip.com
- http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp

(source: formerly http://externip.com/about)

Answer (score 7):

With Powershell 3.0 (Windows 7 default is 2.0) you can use [`Invoke-WebRequest`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx)

**For IPv4:**

```
$tmp =Invoke-WebRequest -URI http://myip.dnsomatic.com/
$tmp.Content
```

**For IPv6:**

```
$tmp =Invoke-WebRequest -URI http://myexternalip.com/raw
$tmp.Content
```

This will give you a variable to work with if you have something specific you want to do with it. I'm actually using this to build a script to upload my router's dynamic IP periodically, have another machine test communication to it at regular intervals, and then update DNS with the latest IP if it has changed so I can access my gear from anywhere by using a name instead of having to constantly chase down the IP.

And of course - as the sites change or their outputs change you'll want to update this accordingly. :)

Comment: This approach worked great for me on windows 10. I needed a one-line command, so ran the above in quotes after `powershell.exe -noprofile -command ""`. Separate the line-break with a semicolon...

Comment: Oneliner? Just run `(Invoke-WebRequest -URI http://myip.dnsomatic.com).Content`

Comment: For me it says that `Internet Explorer engine is not available` so i have to append the `-UseBasicParsing` parameter like this:
```(Invoke-WebRequest -URI http://myip.dnsomatic.com -UseBasicParsing).Content```

Answer (score 5):

I made this batch script to do that a few months ago:

```
@echo off

:: WhatIsMyIP.cmd - returns public IP address
:: requires: wget.exe

if [%1]==[-h] goto :HELP
if [%1]==[--help] goto :HELP
if [%1]==[/?] goto :HELP

wget -q -O %temp%\MyIP http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp
for /f "delims= " %%G in (%temp%\myip) do set PublicIP=%%G & del %temp%\MyIP
echo. & echo Your public IP address is %PublicIP% & echo.
if [%1]==[--clip] echo %PublicIP% | clip
goto :EOF

:HELP
echo. & echo Usage: whatismyip [--clip] & echo.
goto :EOF

:EOF
```

It gives you the option to put the IP address in the clipboard and it sets an environmental variable - `%PublicIP%`.

---

**SIMPLER METHOD:**

Now, I just do this instead:

```
curl icanhazip.com
```

or...

```
curl icanhazip.com | clip
```

...to get the current public IP address into the clipboard.

You need [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/).

Comment: The script from paradroid worked fine but whatsmyip moved the web page to
http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp If you change to this, it works perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
Doesn't need any kind of external software installed.

```
@set @script=0 /*
  @echo off
    set @script=
    cscript //nologo //e:jscript "%~dpnx0"
  exit /b
*/

with (new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')) {
   open('GET', 'http://internet.yandex.ru/', false);
   send();

   WScript.echo(responseText.match(/IPv4:\s(\d+\.){3}\d+/g));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Without third party programs is hard on Windows as Telnet isn't supplied by default, but, if it is there (XP) or turned on (Windows Vista and above), simply type:

```
telnet curlmyip.com 80
```

the screen will flash, and you will just get a cursor... Next type:

```
GET
```

In capital letters... you will then see the headers, followed by your ip (and sorry I blurred it, just showing where it would be!):

[image]

Other answers here obviously work, but, I'm trying to keep to the question on something that can be used on any windows, without third party programs!

For Windows Vista and above, you can install telnet easily (and safely) through `Programs and features`, or use the following command:

```
pkgmgr /iu:”TelnetClient”
```

Comment: That (and most of the answers!) does assume that the source website picks up your ip address accurately - some types of proxies mess this up. I was scraping my ip address off my router cause of this. Interestingly, in these cases, a website that uses a non standard port may work fine.

Comment: Not working with `curlmyip.com`, but tested working with `checkip.dyndns.org`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ifcfg.me](http://ifcfg.me). it supports some internal commands that come with windows by default.

```
curl ifcfg.me
nslookup . ifcfg.me
telnet ifcfg.me
ftp ifcfg.me
finger @ifcfg.me
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I figured out, it's possible to use in-built command to get public IP address but you do have access to internet

```
telnet icanhazip.com
```

or

```
telnet myip.gelma.net
```

Comment: Good catch! Although `icanhazip.com` won’t work for me and the other one doesn’t do IPv6 properly. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to have a solution which works for **Windows** without installing third party tools. So I took the **powershell** option, which should run a script every hour.

You create this script with Notepad

```
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$ip = $wc.DownloadString("http://myexternalip.com/raw")
$LogTime = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss"
Add-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\logs\IPLog.txt $LogTime
Add-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\logs\IPLog.txt "`n"
Add-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\logs\IPLog.txt $ip
Add-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\logs\IPLog.txt "`n"
```

and save it as `getIP.ps1` somewhere. You can call this script either directly in powershell or use the task planer as I did. This is the command for executing:

```
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -File C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\getIP.ps1
```

In the task scheduler you create a new task. At **Trigger** you use the setting 
*daily for every 1 day* and under advanced option you choose *every hour for the duration of immediately*. Also check *Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed* in the **Settings**. Under **Action** you paste the above execution code.

The powershell code can be optimized, because I'm no powershell guru (my first time with it). Now I'm testing if the script is called every hour.

Answer (score 0):

Newest Windows have curl command build-in. Just type

```
curl ip-adresim.app
```

and it will return your public IPv4 or IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

From Powershell:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://ifconfig.me/ip").Content
```

Credit: http://woshub.com/get-external-ip-powershell/

Answer (score -1):

ipchicken.com will return your apparent IP address in text format if you can parse the returning HTML you extract your router's external IP.  Alternately you can install one of those dynamic DNS agents that updates your apparent external IP to an FQDN and then just do nslookup on your FQDN to see your current IP number. There used to be free ones like DynDNS but most of them now require a paid subscription account.