# How to detect WAN IP address changes?

Tags: wan, network-monitoring

I have a software that is very WAN IP Address sensitive, and I am looking for some "monitors" which can detect if WAN changed by ISP, just to react accordingly.

Any good recommendation?

Edit: I would like to restart my software, if the WAN IP does changed. Or at least some feedback or alert.

Comment: What needs to happen if it does change?  Most modern routers allow for use of a dynamic update service like no-ip.com.  The only way to "detect" it is to have a script running locally query a service like whatismyip.com and compare to the last query.  (Be sure to stay within the TOS and only check a few times per hour) Maybe you can edit in more about your actual need for better advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest way to check for dynamic IP change](http://superuser.com/questions/561584/simplest-way-to-check-for-dynamic-ip-change)