# External IP Address , in Windows Tools

Tags: networking

Could you help me to solve this Problem ?

I couldn’t find My IP NAT address (My External IP Address) in Windows Tools 
and I couldn’t to accept something like these answers

“
(1.Make a Script Code

2. Telnet to my Router
3. Uses some Resolver
4. Uses some website to find it)”

I want to find it within some Settings in my windows .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like homework.  Why all the restrictions?

Comment: I'm not positive what you mean by your external IP address, but if you mean the address that the rest of the internet sees, you won't be able to see that in windows as long as you are behind some appliance.

Comment: Use `tracert` and parse the output. First you have to work out where in the tracert output is your public ip address. Hint: that bit is hard.

Comment: Possible dupe: [How do you get your public IP address through the Windows command line?](http://superuser.com/a/990743)

Answer (score 4):

This isn't going to happen. Standard windows tools will not know or show this information, because the windows system has no knowledge of the network NAT configuration.

First, the tools would somehow have to know whether you are concerned about the outside or inside of the network.  There are all kinds of purposes for which the wan side info would be inappropriate, and few where it would be needed.

As far as windows is concerned, a NAT wall is just another router, so there is no default behavior it could apply.

Answer (score 1):

#### Is it possible to get your external IP address through cmd?

Your question is impossible to answer as it stands.

Your external IP address **is not stored in any Windows setting**.

You *may* be able to use `tracert` and parse the output.

- First you have to work out where in the `tracert` output is your external IP address.
- Hint: that bit is hard (see below for the reasons why).

The external (WAN) address can be a public or a private IP address:

- Your ISP provides a WAN address.
- It can be either static/dynamic
- It can be public/private

It all depends on how the ISP has configured **his** network to connect to yours in order to provide you with an internet service.

Comment: Yes , It's Possible .

Comment: @Mahdi If you believe it's possible feel free to [Answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: it's possible to use CMD ...
but I don't know how does it work ...

Comment: <shrug> I've told you one way to do it and I also told you why it is very hard/impossible.

Comment: Ok !
, I got it .