# Can I ssh into a Windows computer if I have ssh installed or are there possible network restrictions?

Tags: windows, networking, ssh

I have access to the Command Prompt in Windows 10 on my company's work computer but there are some restrictions on my user privileges. I don't have super user abilities so I can't grant permissions to new executable files, for example; in other words, I can't install new software without requesting it from a department.

I typed in `ssh` and noticed that ssh is already installed on my system.

Is it possible that this guarantees that I can ssh into my system (from a remote Linux system) or will there possibly be other dependencies needed or some kind of network restriction that may not allow me to use this pre-installed package?

Comment: You absolutely can SSH into a Windows machine with OpenSSH Server installed. However, your permissions won’t change, you still won’t have any elevated permissions. If OpenSSH Sever is not installed then you can’t do it, and without elevated permissions, you probably cannot properly configure it

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft now includes an SSH server with Windows 10.
But unfortunately it is not enabled or configured by default and
**requires Administrator privileges to setup**.

It is installed via
*Settings > Apps > Apps & Features > Optional Features > Add a feature*,
then selecting "OpenSSH Server" (to find it quickly type `ssh`
into the search field).

You will also then need to go into the Services applet, find the
"OpenSSH SSH Server" service and set its Startup to Automatic.

Finally, you will need to ensure that the Firewall is set correctly.
Use the PowerShell command `Get-NetFirewallRule -Name *ssh*`.

For more information, see the article
[SSH Server on Windows 10](https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2020/05/21/ssh-server-on-windows-10.aspx).

Comment: Can someone obtain the IP address used in the linked article, to connect to remote system, following instruction from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/990404/how-do-you-get-your-public-ip-address-through-the-windows-command-line) SE question?

Answer (score 0):

Command `ssh` not producing an error only means you have an SSH client so you can SSH out. To access the system remotely with SSH you need SSH server installed.

Check if your system has SSH service running. If it's there you should be able to access - if firewall or other similar measures don't prevent it. If it's not, there might be ways to get one running without the admin privileges required for installing, but since it's a company-owned system with company-managed/approved software and permissions that also might get you in a lot of trouble.

If you need SSH remote access and it's not available, by far the best way is to present a business case to your manager.